# VS403363: Your personal account does not have access to this. Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

It's weird that I am getting this issue suddenly, all working fine till now and now I am not able to access my azure organization page nor I am able to push any of my changes.

This is what I am getting when I tries to access organization space.

[image]

It's been 4 months and till now everything was working fine, and suddenly I am getting this error.

Here is my information for given account.

[image]

## What I tried so far?

- First of all my linked account is of **gmail**.
- I tried to sign out all the accounts and tried to login with in incognito mode. no success. same error.
- I discussed with my client and he told me that there was no change from his side, still we tried to remove my user and added once again with different roles like Basic, Stack Holder etc. I got invitation all the time but when I try to join/accept that invitation, I will get this same error.
- I have also checked this discussions but nothing worked.
  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/742199/401-uh-oh-you-do-not-have-access.html 
  [VSTS login fails with 401 not authorized - [user] has multiple accounts associated with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038397/vsts-login-fails-with-401-not-authorized-user-has-multiple-accounts-associat)

Not sure where the issue is, any help will be appreciated.'
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With our internal tool, the status of your account(*gmail account*) in that organization is **Pending**. This means you just received the invite message, but haven't **succeed to active** your account in the organization.

This organization has been backed with AAD, and you also have been a member of this directory. Just your AAD role is a `guest`.

If other members which in the same organization could access the org successfully, then your `guest` role will not has any affect because this means this org allow with `AAD guest user` access.

After the above confirmation, please go `https://aex.dev.azure.com/me` to check your detailed profile info. In this page, focus on the left panel:

[image]

Change the directory where you exists, to see which directory the organization(`kt***ah`) is using. As I mentioned, your account status is **Pending** for that organization, which means you have not yet successfully entered the correct directory, do identity verification and login.

Comment: okay, this makes sense. but this was working fine, how come suddenly this stopped? also I have tried lots of time to join but each time I am getting this error. Now, I am not getting this drop down on my left side panel. so can you please elaborate on how to update this pending status. thank you.

Comment: @Bharat, not very sure why it is. When does this organization backed with AAD?Maybe relevant with directory changed. To update the Pending status, please go the correct directly which shown as the pic I shared. The correct directory is the one which you can see the organization name(kt***ah)  in the right panel.

Comment: thanks for quick response. see my updated question. thing is my info page does not contain this drop down at all.

Comment: This seems relevant with your AAD role: guest. Does others could access the org? I saw they are all guest except the org owner. The root solution is suggest the AAD owner to add you as a AAD member. Recently, our team seems got the similar ticket: Users who is guest could not access the org and could not change the directory. But this is not a continuous issue(Our team is investigation). Please contact the owner to remove and re-add you as a member of AAD. Then send you the invitation again.

Comment: @Bharat, welcome. Just at me if you have been a AAD member but still facing the same issue. I will help to check with our internal tool.

Comment: Merlin, I and my client tried this with my user https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal. it worked. I am able to login and see all the projects but somehow I am not able to push my code to repository. I will look into it and add here my solution. thanks for your help though, that's how I get lead..

Comment: @Bharat Awesome! Don’t hesitate to at me if need any assistance. I always here.

Comment: @Bharat. You said that you are having trouble on pushing code? Issue on import the repos? Until yesterday we received many similar issue which caused by our new feature released. Not sure what's the exactly error you are facing, but you can have a try with work around. Please go **preview features** and disable **New Repos landing pages**. We have prepare the fixed code and is deploying to all regions. Hope the issue you saw is what we are investigating.

Comment: yes, Merlin. I am still having that issue. I will surly try this suggested steps once my client gets online. thanks for updates. really appreciate...

Comment: merlin, I am not sure how to reach to this preview features and disable New Repos landing pages. today I tried lot to disable it, but it didn't work. can you please provide me some kind of link or something. thank you.

Comment: @Bharat do you mean you could not found the place of preview feature?

Comment: you said this in your last comment. 'Please go to preview features and disable New Repos landing pages.' now, I am not sure how to access this preview features. please guide me there.

Comment: @Bharat Okay, please go right corner, and click your avatar, you would see the **preview feature** in the drop down panel. This is the old UI design of account panel. Not sure whether you are using old or new account UI. If above mentioned is not what you see, this means you are in New account UI mode. Still click avatar first, and then click the **three dots**. You will see the **preview feature** button at the first line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204568/discussion-between-bharat-and-merlin-liang-msft).

Comment: @Bharat I am out of office and is using my phone to login this SO. Not very convenient to chat, can we talk tomorrow? We could schedule our available time, and I will join it. My available time is 3pm-12pm(UTC+8)

Comment: @Bharat, I saw the error you faced, did you input the PAT token into the password blank while you import the repos from other places?

Comment: I didn't do anything. everytime when I tried to access repo or code from azure, or I want to push my code, it gives this permission error. I am not able to resolve it. so i was thinking to move my project to git. azure is terrible...

Comment: @Bharat As one of azure devops team, so sorry for this.

Comment: @Bharat, Or you can raised the issue on this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=4d7c8158-200d-893b-5161-06d00803fd9c. This can let us work closely. The error you received should just be a issue on permission setting.

Comment: Very useful! Would have taken me a long time to figure this hidden page existed and that I can change which directory my user was associated with.